Equivalence of the two functors $Alt^{k}(-*)$ and $(Alt^{k})^{*}$
I am finishing Vector Analysis of Klaus Jänich. I am stuck at chapter $12$ because I am confused about a notation. I hope some of you could untangle it for me.
Lemma
We can interpret each $\varphi \in (Alt^{k}(V))^{*}$ (the dual of $Alt^{k}(V)$) as an alternating $k-$form on $V^{*}$ according to this canonical identification:
each functional $\varphi$ corresponds to a $k-$form defined as
$$
\tilde{\varphi}(\alpha^{1}, \dots, \alpha^{k}) := \varphi(\alpha_{1} \wedge \dots \wedge \alpha_{k}) \quad \forall \alpha_{1}, \dots, \alpha_{k}.
$$
Knowing this, and given $f: V \to W$ linear between finite dimensional vector spaces, we can prove that the following diagram commutes:
\begin{array}{ccc}
(\text{Alt}_k V)^* & \xrightarrow{(\text{Alt}_k f)^*} & (\text{Alt}_k W)^* \\
\downarrow & & \downarrow \\
\text{Alt}_k (V^*) & \xrightarrow{\text{Alt}_k (f^*)} & \text{Alt}_k (W^*)
\end{array}
Why? I have at least two questions: Does $Alt_{k}(f)^{*}$ indicates the adjoint of $Alt_{k}f,$ where
$$
Alt_{k}(f)(v^{1} \wedge \dots \wedge v^{k}):= f(v^{1}) \wedge \dots \wedge f(v^{k})?
$$
If so, shouldn't the arrow go the other way around?
Edit: Sorry, I found out the arrows directions are all correct, what I missed was the definition of $Alt^{k}f: Alt^{k}(W) \to Alt^{k}(V).$
Given a form $\alpha^{1}\wedge \dots \wedge \alpha^{k} \in Alt^{k}(W)$ then
$$
Alt^{k}(f)(\alpha^{1}\wedge \dots \wedge \alpha^{k})(v_1, \dots, v_{k}) := \alpha^{1}\wedge \dots \wedge \alpha^{k}(f(v_1, \ \dots, \ f(v_{k})).
$$
Thus, the arrows go in the right direction. Despite this, I am still struggling to show that the diagram commute, can someone give me a hand?

You are correct on both counts. It should be going from $W$ to $V$ because $({-})^*$ is contravariant and $Alt_k$ is covariant.

@NicholasTodoroff thank you, so the simbol of $f^*$ in this context indicates the adjoint of $f$, right?

If you mean $f^* : W^* \to V^$ and $f^(\omega) = \omega\circ f$, then yes.

@NicholasTodoroff unfortunately I have found that my previous definition was wrong. I edited my question, do you have any insights about this edited version?

I solved the problem I posted, I don't need someone to answer it. The fundamental thing to prove is that
$$
Alt^{k}f(w^1 \wedge \dots \wedge w^{k}) = (f^{*}(w^{1}) \wedge \dots \wedge f^{*}(w^{k})) \quad \forall w_{i} \in W^{*}.
$$
By writing the definition of Alt^{k}f and that of wedge product we obtain
$$
Alt^{k}f(w^1 \wedge \dots \wedge w^{k})(v_1, \dots, v_k)= w^1 \wedge \dots \wedge w^{k} (f(v_1), \dots, f(v_k)) \\
= c \cdot \sum_{\tau \in S^{k}} sgn(\tau) \prod_{i=1}^{k}w^{\tau(i)}(f(v_i)) = c \cdot \sum_{\tau \in S^{k}} sgn(\tau) \prod_{i=1}^{k}f^{*}(w^{\tau(i)})(v_i)\\
=  f^{*}(w^1) \wedge \dots \wedge f^{*}(w^{k}).
$$
The constant $c$ is the normalising constant that I don't remember and changes according to different conventions.
